# How to create a custom grip to resize widgets inside a layout?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, layout

I created a label to behave as a grip, to be able to 'customize' the height of widgets that are inside of a `QGridLayout`.

To get the resize working correctly with any kind of widget size, I needed to set both min and maximum height according to the mouse position relative to the grip:

```
            // Adapt the widget size based on mouse movement.
            QPoint delta = e->pos() - mousePos;
            mousePos = e->pos();

            if (delta.y())
                parentHeight += delta.y();
            else
                parentHeight -= delta.y();
            
            parent->setMinimumHeight(parentHeight);
            parent->setMaximumHeight(parentHeight);
```

But this prevents the widget from **growing** together with her `QGridLayout` parent, as the `MaximumHeight` is limited.

An example:

After reducing the height of the GUI and then increasing it again, how I could make the `red` frame grow together with the `blue` frame?

[image]

I thought in "resetting" the `setMaximumHeight` at the `mouseRelease` event, then it could 'grow' again:

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e) { parent->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX); }
```

However, the widget is automatically adjusted by her `QGridLayout` parent:

[image]

Reproducible example as seen in the gif:

```cpp
// gripLabel.h
class GripLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QGridLayout* layout;     
    QWidget* parent;

    bool resizing = false;
    QSize gripSize = QSize(20, 8);
    QPoint mousePos;
    
    int parentHeight = 0;

    GripLabel(QWidget* p = 0) : QLabel()
    {
        parent = p;
        layout = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(parent->layout());

        setMinimumWidth(20);

        // background-color: green
        // debug only, just to be able to see the grip area.
        this->setStyleSheet(R"(
            background-image: url(:/icons/sizegrip);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: bottom right;            
            background-color: green;
        )");
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
    {
        mousePos = e->pos();
        QPoint gripPos = QPoint(width() - gripSize.width(), 
                                height() - gripSize.height());

        // Check if we hit the grip handle.
        if ((mousePos.x() >= gripPos.x()) && (mousePos.y() >= gripPos.y()))
        {
            parentHeight = parent->height();
            resizing = true;
        }
        else
            resizing = false;
    }
    
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
    {
        //parent->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
    {
        if (resizing) 
        {
            // Adapt the widget size based on mouse movement.
            QPoint delta = e->pos() - mousePos;
            mousePos = e->pos();

            if (delta.y())
                parentHeight += delta.y();
            else
                parentHeight -= delta.y();
            
            parent->setMinimumHeight(parentHeight);
            parent->setMaximumHeight(parentHeight);
        }
    }
};
```

---

```cpp
#include "gripLabel.h"
QtWidgetsApplication8::QtWidgetsApplication8(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
    ui.centralWidget->setLayout(layout);


    QFrame* frame = new QFrame(this);
    QGridLayout* frameLayout = new QGridLayout();
    frame->setLayout(frameLayout);
    frame->setObjectName("frame");
    frame->setStyleSheet("#frame { border: 4px solid red; }");

    frame->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    frameLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    GripLabel* grip = new GripLabel(frame);
    frameLayout->addWidget(grip, 0, 1, 0, 1, Qt::AlignRight);

    layout->addWidget(frame, 0, 0);


    QFrame* frame2 = new QFrame(this);
    QGridLayout* frameLayout2 = new QGridLayout();
    frame2->setLayout(frameLayout2);
    frame2->setObjectName("frame2");
    frame2->setStyleSheet("#frame2 { border: 4px solid blue; }");

    frame2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    frameLayout2->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    GripLabel* grip2 = new GripLabel(frame2);
    frameLayout2->addWidget(grip2, 0, 1, 0, 1, Qt::AlignRight);

    layout->addWidget(frame2, 1, 0);


    QSpacerItem* spacer = new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
    layout->addItem(spacer, 2, 0);


    layout->setRowStretch(0, 1);
    layout->setRowStretch(1, 1);
}
```

What I'm missing is find a way to get the widget resized by the `GripLabel` class be able to grow together her parent layout.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why not a [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html)?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I've never used a QSplitter, it could work in this case?

Comment: The `QSplitter` is _the_ widget for the task you try to accomplish. There is a minor difference: the separator bar itself is used as handle to manually resize the neighbor child widgets. Though, this is the usual behavior for such widgets in any widget set I've seen so far...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat im reading/testing it, looks like it really can help i achieve this task, but im getting the same problem, when i resize using my grip and release the button the widgets are adjusted to their max size

Comment: The resizing by the separator is not intuitive, i would like to have the grips below each widget. Do you think calling `QSplitter::setSizes(const QList<int> &list)` from the `GripdLabel` class i could achieve it?

Comment: I wonder about your claim _The resizing by the separator is not intuitive_. It's how splitter widgets work for twenty years or more - in Windows, X11 (any maybe other systems I haven't used yet). Haven't you used any in your daily business?

Comment: If you want to set child window sizes from "outside" [QSplitter::setSizes()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html#setSizes) seems appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this (improvements have to be done with this code so it renders something more pleasant)

QtWidgetsApplication8.h

```
protected :
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
    QFrame* frame;
    QFrame* frame2;
```

QtWidgetsApplication8.cpp

```
void QtWidgetsApplication8::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    frame->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
    frame2->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

EDIT :
It will looks better with that (applying "growing together" only when main window gets higher height)

```
void QtWidgetsApplication8::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    if(event->oldSize().height() < event->size().height())
    {
        frame->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
        frame2->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
    }
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

EDIT : here is the result :
[image: resizeEvent for frames to grow together]

Comment: Happens the same thing, the widget is automatically adjusted by the layout as soon `setMaximumHeight` is "reseted"

Comment: I don't understand what you really want then... are you sure what you expects is "logical" ?
I really have quite what you wanted to have with my code

Comment: I edited my solution with the result I've got, don't you expected that ?

Comment: @William is this what you expected ?